# AngularJS routing not matching route sometimes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I'm experiencing a weird behaviour with an app I'm working on
The app is in PHP and use UI-Router for routing purpose only, it works rather well actually, but since yesterday we are experiencing a weird thing: sometimes it matches the route we defined and sometimes it just jump to the otherwise condition.

Here is a snippet of how roughly the routing page looks like:

```
    .when('/foo',{
      templateUrl:'path',
      controller: 'Controller'
  })
  .when('bar/Add/:idc' ,{
      templateUrl: function(attrs)
      {
          return 'path?idc= ' + attrs.idc;
      },
      controller: 'Controller'
  })
  .when('foobar/Edit/:id/:idc', {
      templateUrl: function(attrs){
          return 'path?id=' + attrs.id + '&idc='+ attrs.idc;
      },
      controller: 'Controller'
  })

  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/default'
  });
```

How can we solve this? I repeat sometimes it just works, sometimes not. We aren't using any cache system at the moment, we tried different browser with the relative incognito mode. AngularJS v. 1.4.8 and PHP 5.

Thanks to everyone who can take us to the light :D

EDIT

Adding some view code for additional inspection. So the App follow a module system, each module have this dir structure:

```
Module
|Controller/Module.Controller.php
|Form/Module.Form.php
|Model/Module.Model.php
|View/Module.*.View.php
|Module.php
```

Module.php call the generic view in the View folder (Module/View/Module.View.php) which render any views is defined for that module. We have a custom autoload class to autoload any classes in the project.
I'm attaching link to the code, which is hosted on pastebin (as there seems to be some formatting problems with stackoverflows code viewer).

Module name: Listini
Genreic view (Listini.View.php) http://pastebin.com/PUNet6rG
Edit view (Listini.Edit.View.php) http://pastebin.com/81vz6d0w

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well it seems that for some reason gets a 404 and therefore it redirects to the `otherwise` statement. Therefore you should share your code related with the route you are experiencing this issue.

Comment: @VassilisPits sorry I was home so couldn't post any code. So I'm posting the code of the views

Comment: What you should do is go to your dev tools, click on preserve log option and try to replicate the issue. Theoretically you'll see something there (like a 404 error or something) and then we can investigate it. Right now it's too generic.

Comment: @VassilisPits I was trying to post the code seems there is a problem with Stackoverflow code snippet tool.. I'll post it to pastebin :/ I'll do that and hope it occurs again, because sometimes itactually works :|

Comment: I tried and luckily it occured, but 404 was caught BUT luckily i tried the url without passing any parameters and it goes straight to the view - which is still strange because there is no route defined for such url.  Suggestions?

Comment: It seems more like an issue with your "backend" than your frontend. Without sharing more I cannot help. Have a nice day

Comment: Which code you need to see?

Comment: @VassilisPits I add some more informations in to the question, provided some code you can can look at. let me know if you need more.

Comment: troubleshooting a "sometimes" through a question here is very difficult.  What triggers this to happen?  Are there specific conditions?  Have you attempted to log the route when it occurs to verify that it is actually what you intended?  Does it happen when clicking a link from the active site or only when coming from an external link?  There are too many possibilities for anyone to do anything other than offer some troubleshooting advice.

Comment: @Claies That's exactly the problem, I don't have a clue what triggers this behaviour. There are link to the view I need to go to and we noted that this behaviour has spread to all the app. I'm using the Firefox Web dev tools to monitor what's happening still no 404 so i'm runnng out of my possibilities. I know it's jsut to vague and myself can't explain whats wrong.

Comment: so are these hitting your server or not hitting your server? are these links external to the app, hand written into your template files, or generated by code in some form?

Comment: They hit the server but it triggers the otherwise statement, they are all internal and handwritten in the templates, we only pass the arguments with PHP code. I've tried also to reach the views by giving the url with a valid parameter but nada still goes to the deafult. It just stop working and start woorking again... I'm not even sure if this is programming or black magic though. anyway the code isn't mine, I'm just an intern who had the bad luck to finish the work(?)

Comment: Oh And now it works when there are no parameters and there is no route defined for that!

Comment: Well to be completely honest, if they are links that are in Angular templates that are hitting your server and then back into a new Angular app instance, the app has larger problems than just hitting the wrong route, since Angular is a Single Page Application Framework that you appear to not be using in a Single Page (on the surface, based on your descriptions so far).

Comment: In other words, clicking a link in angular which goes to a server route that performs some server logic that then passes parameters to a new page that loads a new instance of angular to respond to those parameters is an overall flawed logic.  Angular is designed so that you don't have to go to the server;  if you need server communication, you should do it through APIs.

Comment: @Claies So how can we sort this out? Because honestly it's a big project so chaninging routing now will be a big problem.

Comment: in fact, it's even worse using ui-router to return a server link that in turn loads another instance of angular.  You have taken a framework which is designed to minimize server interaction and turned it into a server communication factory;  this architecture has so many flaws that anything you try is going to be a workaround for the incorrect way you are using the frameworks involved.  I wish you luck, but this isn't a problem that can be solved in a single question here, in my opinion, and definitely shouldn't be done at all if you could avoid it.

Comment: Ok I'm talking with my superiors, any suggestion on which routing system can we replace with so to mimize the works?